# How to integrate ASP.NET Identity with ASP.NET Web API in Ember.js application

Tags: javascript, authentication, ember.js, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm developing an Ember.js application. I already have a web api with ASP.Identity as membership and identity management framework which implemented authentication and authorization. I want to use this authentication mechansism in my Ember application. My plan is like this, after successful login identity will return a token. After that, for each api call I have to pass this token with header. Is this is a best practice? Or is there a good way to handle this scenario? Any link or suggestion will be helpful.

I found articles related to integrate Ember Simple Auth plug-in to Ember application to handle authentication and authorization. Since I already implemented authentication in web api it would be an extra work. Please suggest.

Comment: Yes, token based authentication is pretty commong and a good practice. There are plenty of tutorials on how to do it with Identity: http://www.saifikram.com/2014/06/token-based-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-with-owin An integration with AngularJS for example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/784106/AngularJS-Token-Authentication-using-ASP-NET-Web-A

Answer (score 0):

Ember Simple auth can easily support all kinds of backends via custom authenticators (see https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#implementing-a-custom-authenticator). As you already have the server API in place it should be simple to implement an authenticator that works with it.